# PostgreSQL sql-state: 42601 on SELECT INTO

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Well, i'm trying to create a simple procedure, that check if user with such login, and if no - adding new row in users table. But stuck with unexpected problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_user(character varying, character varying, character varying,character varying,character varying)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    new_user_login ALIAS FOR $1;
    new_user_password ALIAS FOR $2;
    new_user_email ALIAS FOR $3;
    new_user_first_name ALIAS FOR $4;
    new_user_last_name ALIAS FOR $5;
    login_exist bigint;
    new_user_id bigint;
    emails_array character varying array; --yep, it's array of emails
BEGIN       
    SELECT INTO login_exist count(login) FROM users WHERE users.login = new_user_login;
    IF (login_exist = 0) THEN
        SELECT array_append(emails_array, new_user_email);
        INSERT INTO users (login,password,emails,first_name,last_name) 
        VALUES (new_user_login,new_user_password,emails_array,new_user_first_name,new_user_last_name)
        RETURNING id INTO new_user_id;
        RETURN new_user_id;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

It returns sql-state: 42601 on SELECT INTO. But if only count is 0. When login is exist it correctly return 0;
What the problem is? I'm even have no idea what is this.
thx for help;

Comment: Should that not be `SELECT <columns> INTO <variables>...` for the plpgsql construct? Are you sure it's working sometimes?

Comment: You *need* to provide your version of Postgres with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This instruction:

```
SELECT array_append(emails_array, new_user_email);
```

should fail because `array_append` returns the modified array and ignoring the result of the select is not allowed.

If you wanted to append into the source array, this should be:

```
SELECT array_append(emails_array, new_user_email) INTO emails_array;
```

However this is not even necessary. You may simplify your function body into:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO users (login,password,emails,first_name,last_name) 
SELECT new_user_login,new_user_password,array[new_user_email],new_user_first_name,new_user_last_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM users WHERE users.login = new_user_login)
RETURNING id INTO new_user_id;

RETURN coalesce(new_user_id,0);

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [@Daniel already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283866/939860), don't use the outdated `ALIAS` for naming function parameters. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS)

> It's best to use it only for the purpose of overriding predetermined names.

Use [argument names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_user(_login      text
                                       , _password   text
                                       , _email      text
                                       , _first_name text
                                       , _last_name  text)
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _id  bigint;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO users (login, password, emails, first_name, last_name) 
   SELECT _login, _password, ARRAY[_email], _first_name, _last_name
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE login = _login)
   RETURNING id INTO _id;

   RETURN COALESCE(_id, 0);
END
$func$;
```