# Return dynamic table with unknown columns from PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, polymorphism, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, return-type

I need to create a function that checks on a given table if the `infowindow` field exists. If it exists the function must return `select * from table` but if it does not, it must return an additional `id` field:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getxo_ocx_cincu_preparar_infowindow(
                                              guretabla character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    tabla ALIAS FOR $1;

BEGIN

IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1
   FROM   pg_namespace n
   JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
   JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid 
   WHERE  n.nspname = current_schema()  -- default to current schema
   AND    c.relname = tabla
   AND    a.attname = 'infowindow'
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped)
THEN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * from ' ||tabla ;
ELSE
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT *, ID:' || id::text ||' as infowindow
                                   from ' ||tabla ;
END IF;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

If I use `RETURNS SETOF RECORDS`, when I do the select to the function I need to specify the columns, which I don't know. And if I use `RETURNS TABLE` I need to specify the fields too, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You forgot to mention your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is hard to solve, because SQL demands to know the return type *at call time*.
Also, a plpgsql function needs to have a *well defined return type*.

If you choose to return **anonymous records**, you get what you defined: anonymous records. Postgres does not know what's inside. Therefore, a column definition list is *required* to decompose the type.

There are various workarounds, depending on exact requirements. If you have any way of knowing the return type *at call time*, I suggest **polymorphic types** as outlined in the last chapter of this answer ("Various complete table types"):

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

But that does not cover adding another column to the return type *at runtime inside the function*. That's just not possible. I would **rethink the whole approach**.

As for your current approach, the closest thing I can think of would be a temporary table ([or a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15675036/939860)), that you query in a *second call* within a **single transaction**.

You have a couple of **other problems in your code**. See notes below.

### Proof of concept

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_plus_infowindow (_tbl regclass)  -- parameter name
  RETURNS void  -- no direct return type
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tmp text := quote_ident(_tbl::text || '_tmp');  -- apending _tmp for temp table
BEGIN
   -- Create temp table only for duration of transaction
   EXECUTE format(
      'CREATE TEMP TABLE %s ON COMMIT DROP AS
       SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 0'
      ,_tmp, _tbl
     );

   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_attribute a
      WHERE  a.attrelid = _tbl
      AND    a.attname  = 'infowindow'
      AND    a.attisdropped = FALSE
      )
   THEN
      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT * FROM %s', _tmp, _tbl);
   ELSE
     -- This is assuming a NOT NULL column named "id"!!
      EXECUTE format($$
         ALTER  TABLE %1$s ADD COLUMN infowindow text;
         INSERT INTO %1$s
         SELECT *, 'ID: ' || id::text
         FROM   %2$s$$
        ,_tmp, _tbl
        );
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

The call has to be in a single transaction. You may have to start an explicit transaction, depending on your client.

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT f_tbl_plus_infowindow ('tbl');
SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;  -- do something with the returned rows
ROLLBACK;               -- or COMMIT, does not matter here
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=258ad13a8829c672135f312baa4ae3fa)*
<sub>[Old sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed4f0/1)</sub>

Alternatively you could let the temporary table live for the duration of the session. Be wary of naming collisions with repeated calls, though.

#### Notes

Use parameter names instead of the [outdated `ALIAS` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341192/939860).

To actually "default" to the current schema, use the simpler query I display. Using `regclass` does the trick automatically. Details:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

In addition, this also avoids syntax errors and possible **SQL injection** from non-standard (or maliciously malformed) table names in your original code.

The code in your `ELSE` clause wouldn't work at all.

`TABLE tbl;` is basically short for `SELECT * FROM tbl;`.

[Details on `format()` in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

Comment: Would it be possible to return a type containing an id and jsonb where the jsonb contains dynamically built columns with values?

Comment: @Alex Yes, no problem with that.