# How to return a table by rowtype in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, polymorphism, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to implement a function that returns a table with the same structure as an input table in the parameter, using PL/pgSQL (PostgreSQL 9.3). Basically, I want to update a table, and return a copy of the updated table with plpgsql. I searched around SO and found several related questions (e.g. [Return dynamic table with unknown columns from PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929707) and [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/)), which lead to the following minimal test example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_val(_lookup_tbl regclass)
RETURNS _lookup_tbl%rowtype AS --problem line
$func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s SET val = 2 RETURNING * ; ', _lookup_tbl);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I can't get past giving the correct return type for `TABLE` or `SETOF RECORD` in the `problem line`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957098/683218):

> SQL demands to know the return type at call time

But I think the return type (which I intend to borrow from the input table type) is known. Can some one help explain if it is possible to fix the signature of the above PL/pgSQL function?

Note, I need to parametrize the input table and return the update of that table. Alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have so far looks good. The missing ingredient: [**polymorphic types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_val(_tbl_type anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement  -- problem solved
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      'UPDATE %s SET val = 2 RETURNING *;'
     , pg_typeof(_tbl_type))
     );
END
$func$;
```

Call (important):

```
SELECT * FROM change_val(NULL::some_tbl);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=15804dbb31969a9c3ec57635853806d2)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0dfca/1)</sub>

See (last paragraph):

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Thanks a lot! (esp. for the sqlfiddle:).

Comment: Is there any way i can call like SELECT * FROM change_val('some_tbl');????

Comment: @RamCh: No. The return type has to be declared at function declaration time.