# Function returning a table for given table and column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Lets say I have a table named `static` in two different databases `houses` and `apartments`.

`static` table contains the static information of houses such as `house_size`, `no_rooms`, `pool`, `spa`.

`static` table in `houses` database has columns like this:

```
pool    spa house_size  sauna   no_rooms
   1    1         25    1       2
   1    0         35    1       3
```

`static` table in `apartments` database has columns like this:

```
pool    spa house_size  sauna   
   1    1         25    1       
   1    0         35    1
```

I want to run below query without raising any error. Currently, I get error as `no_rooms` column does not exists in `apartments.public.static`.

```
select pool, case when spa = 1 then 1 else 0 end as has_spa,
      sauna, house_size, case when no_rooms > 2 then 1 else 0 end as rooms 
from static;
```

Solution I tried:

```
WITH static_new AS (SELECT s.*     
FROM (SELECT 0 AS no_rooms) AS dummy 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
( SELECT
      pool, spa, sauna, house_size, no_rooms
  FROM static
)  AS s on true)
SELECT * FROM static_new;
```

It works, but this query becomes messy when there are more columns involved.

What I am looking for:

1. Create a function that takes column names and table name and then does the join which I am doing in above query and returns a table. (Should be generic and work for given column names and table name in parameter and return a table.)
2. Any other nice and tidy solution?

Comment: Just fix the data by adding `no_rooms` to the table that doesn't have it.  Or create a view in both databases with the same name where the value added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a strictly typed language and Postgres functions must declare their return type. Returning a variable number of columns from a function is only possible with workarounds, like polymorphic types. See:

- [How to return a table by rowtype in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649910/how-to-return-a-table-by-rowtype-in-pl-pgsql/27652936#27652936)

But we can't work with the row type in your case, as that varies from database to database. The remaining option: return **anonymous records** and provide a column definition list with every call. I don't usually recommend this, as providing a column definition list with every call can be tedious - and often pointless. But yours might be one of the rare use cases where it makes sense.

Still, you have to ***know* the data type** of possibly missing columns. I'll assume `integer` for the purpose of this demo. Else you have to pass data types additionally and build the query accordingly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_select(_tbl regclass
                                          , _cols VARIADIC text[])  -- ①
  RETURNS SETOF record     -- ② anonymous records
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE    -- ③ dynamic SQL
   format(
      'SELECT %s FROM %s'  -- ④ safe against SQLi
    , (
      SELECT string_agg(COALESCE(quote_ident(a.attname)
                              , '0 AS ' || quote_ident(t.col)  -- assuming integer!
                                ), ', ' ORDER  BY t.ord) -- ⑤
      FROM   unnest(_cols) WITH ORDINALITY t(col, ord)   -- ⑤
      LEFT   JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = _tbl    -- ⑥
                                AND a.attnum > 0
                                AND NOT a.attisdropped 
                                AND a.attname = t.col
      )
    , _tbl
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call (important!)

```
SELECT *
FROM   f_dynamic_select('static', 'pool', 'spa', 'sauna', 'house_size', 'no_rooms')
AS t(pool int, spa int, house_size int, sauna int, no_rooms int); -- ② column definition list
```

Your example call, with expressions based on these columns:

```
SELECT pool, case when spa = 1 then 1 else 0 end as has_spa  -- ⑦ expressions
     , sauna, house_size
     , case when no_rooms > 2 then 1 else 0 end as rooms 
FROM f_dynamic_select('static', 'pool', 'spa', 'sauna', 'house_size', 'no_rooms')
AS t(pool int, spa int, house_size int, sauna int, no_rooms int);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=954c72c0565e8984c857cdb226957d61)*

① The function takes a table name as `regclass` type. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

... followed by an arbitrary list of column names - in meaningful order. `VARIADIC` should be convenient for this. See:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)

Note that we pass column names as case-sensitive, single-quoted strings. Not (double-quoted) identifiers.

② This may be the first time ever I recommend returning anonymous records from a function - after close to 1000 answers on the [plpgsql] tag. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> If the function has been defined as returning the `record` data type,
> then an alias or the key word `AS` must be present, followed by a column
> definition list in the form `( column_name data_type [, ... ])`. The
> column definition list must match the actual number and types of
> columns returned by the function.

③ [The manual on dynamic SQL.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

④ Safe against SQL injection, because the table name is passed as `regclass`, and the `SELECT` list is concatenated using `quote_ident()` carefully. See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

⑤ Use `WITH ORDINALITY` to preserve original order of columns. See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

⑥ `LEFT JOIN` to the system catalog [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) to identify existing columns. See:

- [Select columns with particular column names in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800367/select-columns-with-particular-column-names-in-postgresql/15800497#15800497)

⑦ Move expressions building on the passed columns to the outer `SELECT`.

---

Disclaimer: I would only introduce this level of sophistication if I *had* to. Maybe you can work with simple views in each database after all?

Answer (score 0):

Don't muck with the queries.  Add a view to both databases with all the columns.  In the first database:

```
create view v_static as
    select pool, spa house_size, sauna, no_rooms
    from status;
```

In the second:

```
create view v_static as
    select pool, spa house_size, sauna, null as no_rooms
    from status;
```

Then use the view instead of the base table.

Comment: do you know how can I write a function that accepts column names as parameters and return a table?

Comment: @AwaishKumar . . . That doesn't seem like a reasonable solution to the problem you have raised in this question.  You can ask a *new* question if you want to do something like that.

Comment: I have added in the last 2 things, I want to get from the question? 1) is that I am looking for a function to do the stuff, I am doing?