# Dynamic Query Creation and Execution PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have below two tables and two `pl/pgsql` functions.

```
CREATE TABLE tt1(id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE tt2(id int, name text);

INSERT INTO tt1 VALUES (1,'name1');
INSERT INTO tt1 VALUES (2,'name2');
INSERT INTO tt1 VALUES (3,'name3');
INSERT INTO tt2 VALUES (4,'name4');
INSERT INTO tt2 VALUES (5,'name5');
INSERT INTO tt2 VALUES (6,'name6');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_string() RETURNS TEXT  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
query1 TEXT:='';
BEGIN
    query1 := 'SELECT * FROM tt1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tt2';      
    RETURN query1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_generated_string() RETURNS VOID     AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
       -- Need to modify here to get the result same as below query by 
       -- calling above function.
       -- "SELECT * FROM tt1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tt2"
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

`query_string` function returns the query *string*.
How can i modify the "use_generated_string" function so that I can get the result of the below query by calling the `use_generated_string` function.

```
SELECT * FROM tt1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tt2;
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_generated_string() RETURNS VOID     AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN EXECUTE(query_string()) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.name;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT use_generated_string();

NOTICE:  name1
NOTICE:  name2
NOTICE:  name3
NOTICE:  name4
NOTICE:  name5
NOTICE:  name6
 use_generated_string 
----------------------

(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the return type (and keep the called SQL fixed to that type) you can do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_generated_string() RETURNS TABLE( c1 INT, c2 TEXT ) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query_string();
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

If the return type should remain dynamic, this is a delicate problem and I suggest to start with reading [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter)'s [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929707/return-dynamic-table-with-unknown-columns-from-pl-pgsql-function) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557).

[klin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995738/klin)'s answer avoids the whole problem by using `RAISE NOTICE`, which is quite clever, but I'm unsure how one would go about using the results of such a call, except for manual text parsing.